# Does anyone know why I'm getting this asp.net error? CS1061 linqtotwitter

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, linq-to-twitter

Using linqtotwitter I was trying to search for tweets and display them in a table using this model:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;


namespace test.Models
{
    public class TweetSearchModel
    {
        [DisplayName("Tweet ID")]
        public ulong ID { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Screen Name")]
        public string ScreenName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Tweet")]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        internal object ToListAsync()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

This View:

```
@model IEnumerable<test.Models.TweetSearchModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
}

<table>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ScreenName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Text)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

and this controller:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using aLevel.Models;
using LinqToTwitter;
using System.Collections.Generic.I;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace test.Controllers
{
    public class QueriesController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Queries
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ActionName("Search")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> SearchAsync()
        {
            var auth = new MvcAuthorizer
            {
                CredentialStore = new SessionStateCredentialStore()
            };

            var ctx = new TwitterContext(auth);

            var searchResponse =
                await
                (from search in ctx.Search
                 where search.Type == SearchType.Search &&
                       search.Query == "\"LINQ to Twitter\""
                 select search)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

            var tweets =
                await
                (from tweet in searchResponse.Statuses
                 select new TweetSearchModel
                 {
                     ID = tweet.ID,
                     ScreenName = tweet.ScreenName,
                     Text = tweet.Text
                 })
                 .ToListAsync();

            return View(tweets);
        }
    }
}
```

However the ".ToListAsync" is throwing up an error "CS1061  'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync' and no extension method 'ToListAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`searchResponse.Statuses` is a `List<Status>`, so you are doing a LINQ to Objects query. LINQ to Objects ([Enumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.110).aspx)) doesn't have a `ToListAsync` and I'm not sure that it should have since the query doesn't result in an out-of-process operation - it's in-memory only. You can use a non-async operator, like this:

```
        var tweets =
            (from tweet in searchResponse.Statuses
             select new TweetSearchModel
             {
                 ID = tweet.ID,
                 ScreenName = tweet.ScreenName,
                 Text = tweet.Text
             })
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

`ToListAsync` is an extension method with a parameter `cancellationToken`, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dn220261.aspx. So you need to pass a value to the parameter `cancellationToken` to get rid of the compiler error.